# How can I animate my graph with matplotlib so that it looks like the data points are moving?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I have two 2D arrays and I want to display the data in a scatter graph so it will look like the points are moving. So I want the first set of x and y data to be plotted then disappear to be replaced by the next set of x and y data etc.

the code I have currently just plots all the data points and joins them up, effectively tracing out the paths of the data points.

```
pyplot.figure()
    for i in range(0,N):
        pyplot.plot(x[i,:],y[i,:],'r-')
pyplot.xlabel('x /m')
pyplot.ylabel('y /m')
pyplot.show()
```

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `matplotlib` docs contain some [animation examples](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/animation/index.html) that may be useful. They all use the [`matplotlib.animation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) API, so I'd suggest you read through that for some ideas. From the examples, here's a simple animated sine curve using [`FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)        # x-array
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    return line,

#Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init,
    interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ive seen this before, none of the examples seem applicable to my program. is there any way i can get what i want without having to rewrite all the other functions which set the data in the x and y arrays?